# Why does a combined comparison fail when something is put behind it in a block statement?

Tags: ruby, comparison, block, anonymous-function, behavior

I am learning Ruby for the first time and I found that inside of a block statement when using the combined comparison operator (or spaceship operator) that a statement placed before the operator will run but a statement placed afterward will cause an error. I discovered this by playing with semicolons.

`list.sort { |item1, item2| puts "foo"; item1 <=> item2 }` works but

`list.sort { |item1, item2| item1 <=> item2; puts "foo" }` fails.

I tried this outside of a block statement and the problem goes away. I then tried on multi-line block statements like

```
list.sort do |item1, item2|
  item1 <=> item2
  puts "foo"
end
```

and it has the same problem as the single line block.

Does anyone know what is going on?

The best explanation I have thought of is that <=> uses splat-like parameter functionality and is sucking in the text after item 2, but I don't know why it would happen in a block statement but not outside of one or why it is ignoring the semicolon and newlines. A cursory search hasn't turned up any useful documentation.

Edit: The error I get when using Codeacadamy.com's compiler is "comparison of String with String failed."

Edit2:

```
ruby -e '
> list = ["one", "two", "three"]
> list.sort { |f, s| f <=> s; puts "foo" }
> puts list
> '
foo
-e:3:in `sort': comparison of String with String failed (ArgumentError)
from -e:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What error you got? As you said it fails.. We need to look at your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
list.sort do |item1, item2|
  item1 <=> item2
  puts "foo"
end
```

Ruby looks at the return value of *the block* to determine the comparison. Since you have `puts "foo"` at the end of the block, the result of the custom compare will be the output of `puts "foo"` (which is `nil`). You want the comparator to be the last thing you do in the block.

Comment: Thank you. I had forgotten that ruby returns the last evaluated expression if there is no return statement.